# Error "~" is not a valid key name (AutoHotkey 1.1.30.00)

Tags: autohotkey

This is my old source code which is not running in the new version of AutoHotkey.
please fix this code.

> Error "~" is not a valid key name

```
#Persistent
#SingleInstance force

DetectHiddenWindows, On
SetTitleMatchMode 2


Loop, 0x7f
Hotkey, % "*~". chr(A_Index), WhickKey
Return

WhickKey:
  MsgBox %A_ThisHotkey%
Return
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Literal strings must be enclosed in double quotes to distinguish them from variables.

```
#Persistent
#SingleInstance force

DetectHiddenWindows, On
SetTitleMatchMode 2


Loop, 0x7f
Hotkey, % ""*~"" . chr(A_Index), WhickKey
Return

WhickKey:
  MsgBox %A_ThisHotkey%
Return
```

https://autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm#Expressions